# Nginx Setting expires headers cause 404

Tags: nginx, cache, http-status-code-404

i'm using nginx as reverse proxy. I'm already redirect port 80 to 8080, redirect non-www to www and enabled gzip. Al this works.

Now i need add expires headers

Following many posts and answers to this question i add

```
location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpeg|jpg|png|woff|ttf|otf|svg|woff2|eot)$ {
    expires 30d;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

But when i restart nginx, all my static files, that matches with location cannot but found.

I tried figure out by my self but without success.

Follow my default.com

```
proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=nginx_cache_zone:10m inactive=60m;
proxy_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";

upstream originserver  {
  server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
  server_name  mysite.com;
  rewrite ^(.*) $scheme://www.mysite.com$1 permanent;
}

server {

  listen 80;
  server_name www.mysite.com;  

  location /{
    try_files $uri @backend;
  }

  location @backend {
    proxy_pass  http://originserver;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }

  location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpeg|jpg|png|woff|ttf|otf|svg|woff2|eot)$ {
    expires 30d;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
  }

}
```

How can i fix it?

Thanks

Comment: You are missing a `root` statement in your `server` block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not `expires`.

The problem is that you haven't told nginx where the files are. This is done with the [`root`](http://nginx.org/r/root) directive, which should be placed within the `server` block.

Comment: I read something like this, but this static files are deployed within wildfly10 server. I should found the deploy folder and set root to this location?

Comment: @ViniciusRoberto Right, nginx cannot read a war file directly, so you have to do an exploded deployment and point nginx to the document root of the static files.

Comment: thanks for help me! I changed my root and copy my static files to this location and works =D! Now i have to look how i do this easy on wildfly.